# MySQL queries very slow

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a very big database that keeps getting bigger everyday. But I don't really understand how I can use it faster. I also don't know how indexes work.

This are the tables in my database:
First table is a table with all vehicle information:

nm_voertuig:

```
+----+----------+------+--------+--------+-------+
| id | kenteken | merk | model  | deuren | kleur |
+----+----------+------+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 12KT43   | Opel | ZAFIRA |      5 | Blue  |
|  2 | G345CP   | Audi | A3     |      3 | Black |
+----+----------+------+--------+--------+-------+
```

[image]
In this table are like 500000 rows.

nm_voertuig_statistieken:

```
+----+------------+----------+-------+---------+
| id |   datum    | kenteken | prijs | kmstand |
+----+------------+----------+-------+---------+
|  1 | 2016-01-05 | 12KT43   |  5000 |  150000 |
|  1 | 2016-01-06 | 12KT43   |  4900 |  150000 |
|  2 | 2016-01-05 | G345CP   | 12000 |  100000 |
+----+------------+----------+-------+---------+
```

[image]
Everyday the database will be filled with the price of that day. So as long as the car is still available it wil get a new row every day.

So for example I want to get the minimum and maximum mileage of an Opel Zafira.
This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT      MIN(kmstand), MAX(kmstand)
FROM        (
                SELECT v.id
                FROM nm_voertuig v
                WHERE merk = 'Opel' AND model = 'ZAFIRA'
            ) AS cnt
JOIN nm_voertuig_statistieken vs
ON cnt.id = vs.id
```

It takes very long to execute this query:
[image]

What can I do to make the queries faster?

**EDIT:**
Explain select * from nm_voertuig: 
[image]

Explain select * from nm_voertuig_statistieken:
[image]

Comment: Why make an image from the well formated text output?

Comment: Your columns don't seem to match your index fields...

Comment: @juergend When I pasted the text it was not formatted well anymore :D

Comment: images do nothing for us. do `show create table myTable` for each relevant table always

Comment: we will format the text for you

Comment: @ChristianF the explain is included in my post (?)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't notice it there.

Comment: And let's first figure out the indexes you have before someone recommends adding any

Comment: @WouterdenOuden: Just paste the text into the question editor. Then mark the text and push the <code> button of the editor.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I included a explain for the example query in my post. The query takes about 20 seconds with the data for about ten days. The query in the answer takes forever.

Comment: remove subquery (is unuseful)

Comment: @JoeTaras It's much faster with the subquery, so I think it is useful

Comment: @WouterdenOuden: Strange! Maybe, how you've written in answer Linoff comment, you've some problem when you've saved the index.

Comment: Now with the right indexes it is indeed unuseful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should rewrite the query.  Subqueries in MySQL incur overhead for materialization.  So:

```
SELECT MIN(vs.mileage), MAX(vs.mileage)
FROM nm_voertuig v JOIN
     nm_voertuig_statistieken vs
     ON v.id = vs.id
WHERE v.make = 'Opel' AND v.model = 'ZAFIRA';
```

Then, for this index, you want the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nm_voertuig_make_model_id
    ON nm_voertuig(make, model, id);

CREATE INDEX idx_nm_voertuig_statistieken_id_milage
    ON nm_voertuig_statistieken(id, mileage);
```

Comment: It's much slower without the subquery

Comment: @WouterdenOuden Did you createthe index?

Comment: I did create these indexes. This query takes forever.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the execution plan?  One possibility is that the collation of the column in the table is different from the default collation.  This can prevent an index from being used.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm not sure if thats what you mean by execution plan.

Comment: I think it works now. For some reason the index wasn't saved.